# Glassfish not updating after code change

Tags: eclipse, glassfish-4.1

I'm using glassfish 4.1 and when I make any changes in the javascript file from eclipse, the glassfish server isn't updating, I mean it isn't building. The glassfish server still shows it is synchronized even after making any changes to the files.
What could be the cause of this issue?
Will greatly appreciate your help and thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you telling it to build, or is automatic building enabled?

Comment: Yes, the automatic build is enabled.